# While using https://github.com/o19s/solr-to-es to migrate data from SOLR to Elasticsearch, it is possible to migrate all nodes at once in parallel?

Tags: elasticsearch, parallel-processing, solr, migration

I am considering migrating data from SOLR to Elasticsearch using https://github.com/o19s/solr-to-es

The Readme md states
"... will page through all documents on the local Solr, and submit them to the local Elasticsearch server".

Leads me to think that there is a one-to-one mapping between SOLR node and an Elastic node. And this python script will move data from one Solr Node to its corresponding Elastic Node.

If there is a multi-node Solr cluster and multi-node ES cluster... can this command be run in parallel in all the nodes without affecting indexing performance?

Or should it be run serially on each SOLR node?

I am trying to estimate how much time will the migration take.

Haven't tried using the script. Just the read the Readme.md. It portrays that this is some form of local transfer from Solr to ES. So I wonder if parallelism can be introduced.

Answer (score 0):

The way it works is that Solr nodes operate as a cluster the same way as Elasticsearch nodes do. So when you point a query at the Solr endpoint, you don't get to choose a specific node to read from, you simply specify the collection you want to scroll over using a specific query (i.e. `--solr-query SOLR_QUERY`). The collection itself is spread among all (or some of) the nodes of the Solr cluster.

The same way, on the destination side, you simply specify in which Elasticsearch index (i.e. `elasticsearch_index`) the data needs to be copied to.

You don't need to concern yourself with node-to-node data copy because that's not how it works. So if you have several collections to copy, then you can definitely start one process per collection/index, but if you only have a single collection to copy, then a single process is all you need and it will happily scroll over all your documents in the Solr collection and send them away to your Elasticsearch cluster.

Comment: Thanks Val. That helps. This is not a node-to-node transfer. Rather it is a cluster to cluster with index as the object / unit that is being transferred.

Comment: Also it looks like the script can be installed anywhere.. as long as it has network access to the SOLR and ES, it is good to go.

Comment: Exactly, you can definitely spin up multiple processes (one per cluster/collection), and you'll simply be limited by the capacity of the source cluster to deliver you the data and the destination cluster to ingest it. That needs to be tuned